# How do I create/connect to a Docker Azure service bus (using Python SDK)?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, azureservicebus

I'm using the Python 3.8 SDK for Azure service bus, (azure-servicebus v. 0.50.3).  I use the following code to send a message to a topic ...

```
service = ServiceBusService(service_namespace,
                        shared_access_key_name=key_name,
                        shared_access_key_value=key_value)
msg = Message(json.dumps({'type': 'my_message'}))
service.send_topic_message(topic_name, msg)
```

How do I create a Docker image that runs the service bus with a topic or two already created?  I found this image

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    azure_sb:
        container_name: azure_sb
        image: microsoft/azure-storage-emulator
        tty: true
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "10000:10000"
            - "10001:10001"
            - "10002:10002"
```

but I'm unclear how to connect to it using the code I have or if the above is even a valid service bus image.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Service Bus does not provide a docker image. The image that you are using (`microsoft/azure-storage-emulator`) is for the Azure Storage system, which can provide similar queuing capabilities with [Azure Storage Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction). For more details check out [How to use Azure Queue storage from Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=python).

If you need to use Azure Service Bus locally, check out the [GitHub Issue: Local Development story?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/223). TLDR: Use AMQP libraries and connect to another AMQP provider for local, and swap out for Service Bus in production.

Comment: WIth the AMQP route, can I use a Docker image to simulate the messaging system and do I have to change any of the code that I have?   I don't want to use one code base for communicating with the testing (Docker) framework and anotehr for communicating with the prod system, as that would defeat the purpose of testing in the first place.